# Is it possible to sort a file by part of a line?

Tags: shell, sorting, scripting, sed, cut

I am writing shell scripts and I have a file of students and their information (inputFile.txt):

```
Bonerake:Nicole:1011:410-111-0500:CS:09-12-1985
Fugett:Brandon:8188:410-111-0020:Biology:06-29-1982
Bozick:Julia:0333:410-111-0900:English:01-18-1984
Freeman:Andrew:7747:410-111-0060:Business:03-14-1988
Carroll:Sandra:4044:410-111-0000:History:12-19-1987
Everett:Terry:8666:410-111-0100:CS:01-24-1986
Boyer:Dennie:2212:410-111-0080:Math:08-02-1983
```

I am supposed to sort based on what part of the information the user entered (ie first name, last name, etc.). I am able to do this for last name because it is the first in each line. However, I cannot seem to progress onto any other piece of information. This is what I have tried for sorting by first name, and nothing happens:

```
sortStudents(){
echo -e "Which information would you like to sort students by?"
echo -e "\t1) Last Name"
echo -e "\t2) First Name"
echo -e "\t3) Student ID"
echo -e "\t4) Phone Number"
echo -e "\t5) Major"
echo -e "\t6) Birthday"
echo -e "\t*** Input choice: \c"
read choice

case "$choice" in
    1) sort inputFile.txt -o inputFile.txt ;;
    2) cut -d: -f2 inputFile.txt | sort inputFile.txt -o inputFile.txt ;;
esac

return $TRUE
}
```

I used `-f2` because I think that that means go to the second field separated by deliminators. I've searched and searched; tried multiple different `cut` and `sed` and `grep` commands, but I cannot seem to find the one with the correct options that I need. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The `-t` and `-k` options to `sort` will allow you to set the delimiter to `:` and choose which field to sort by respectively. e.g., `sort -t: -k2 inputFile.txt` should sort by first name.

Comment: You could use the Schwartzian Transform technique from perl (duplicate the chosen column to prefix the line, sort, then remove the prefixed column).  Or just use perl ftw!

Comment: `cut -d: -f2 inputFile.txt | sort` sorts the results based on second field(first name).

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, the sort command really should be reading from the standard input:

```
2) cut -d: -f2 inputFile.txt | sort - -o inputFile.txt ;;
```

(which is probably why it doesn't look sorted)

However, in this case, you should be using sort's built-in options:

```
sort -t: -k$choice inputFile.txt -o inputFile.txt
```

The manpage describes the options:

```
   -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
          start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)

   -t, --field-separator=SEP
          use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
```